# Why use R^2 adjusted over R^2 in multiple regression?

Tags: correlation

I read that when adding variables or predictors to the multiple regression model, R^2 tends to go up even if the variable or predictor doesn't add any predictive power. Why is this?

In linear regression, I understand $R^2$ to equal:
$$R^2 = 1 - SSE/SST$$

Why does this go up when we add a new variable or predictor to the model regardless of whether the new variable adds predictive value? Why do we need adjusted $R^2$?

I understand $R^2$ to equal the % of variability explained by the model.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because adding variables to a model can just randomly align to some kind of random variance (i.e. noise). Pure chance could make it seems like its a meaningful predictor rather than its real explanatory power. If you throw mud on the wall, some of it will stick.

So what an adjusted r squared does is subtract the expected random luck of prediction from your r squared value.

Its like the old saying, a broken clock is right twice a day. R squared counts those two times and adjusted r square kicks them out.

Answer (score 0):

In your formula $SST$ is a constant and is the same regardless of how you want to model your multiple linear regression model.

$SSE$ is an non-decreasing function over the number of predictors. It goes up (bounded by $SST$) unless the new predictor is perfectly correlated with existing predictors. You can think like this: in the worse case the new predictor can get a zero coefficient, so adding a new predictor should never worsen the performance.

Thus, as you add more predictors into the model the $R^2$ measure never decrease. This is bad for forming a predictive model because $R^2$ encourages overfitting. Adjusted $R^2$ takes that into account and put a penalty for the number of predictors you have in the model.

However, if your goal is not to predict but for exploratory analysis. It's reasonable to use the $R^2$ measure.

Comment: You said " It goes up (bounded by SSTSST) unless the new predictor is perfectly correlated with existing predictors". Why? Why does it go up everytime we add a new predictor? What if the new predictor is anti-correlated with the existing predictors?

Comment: @Jwan622 You mean negatively perfectly correlated? It's still counted as "perfectly" correlated, just that the sign is negative.

Comment: @Jwan622 When you add a predictor, your model might improve by small margin or significant margin, depending on the new predictor. But it will never make the model worse, because you can always set the coefficient to **zero**.